# Nao consigo rodar esta dando erro de indetação o que está errado

Tags: python

```
def main():

    q = Queue()
    i=1


    while(q.isFull()==False):
        digitado = input ("digite um numero para inserir na fila: ")
        numLido = int(digitado)
        q.enqueue(numLido)
        i+=1


    while (True):

        x = input ("Digite uma opção: ")       
        print ("1. Imprimir uma fila (sem destruí-la)")
        print ("2. Copiar uma fila para outra")
        print ("3. Verificar se duas filas são iguais")
        print ("4. Remover um elemento da fila, conservando o restante da fila.")
        print ("0. Para SAIR")

        if (x == 1):
            q.imprime()

        elif (x == 2):

        elif (x == 3):

        elif (x == 4):

        elif (x == 0):
            print ("SAIU...")
            break
        else:
            print("ERRO! ")       

if name=="main": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei de onde está vindo esta classe `Queue`, mas se for do próprio Python, do módulo `queue`, há muitos erros no seu programa. Mas considerando que seja uma implementação própria e que todos os métodos utilizados existem, listo os erros:

1. Sua condição para executar `main` está errada. O correto é:

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```
2. Não faz sentido ler a opção antes de exibir as possibilidades e se for compará-la com valores inteiros, é necessário convertê-la para inteiro.

   ```
   print ("1. Imprimir uma fila (sem destruí-la)")
   print ("2. Copiar uma fila para outra")
   print ("3. Verificar se duas filas são iguais")
   print ("4. Remover um elemento da fila, conservando o restante da fila.")
   print ("0. Para SAIR")
   x = int(input("Digite uma opção: "))
   ```
3. O seu problema de identação está nos `elif` que não executam código algum. O Python não permite isso. Se desejas implementar a lógica mais tarde, mas mesmo assim manter as condições, utilize a diretiva `pass`.

   ```
   if (x == 1):
       q.imprime()

   elif (x == 2):
       pass

   elif (x == 3):
       pass

   elif (x == 4):
       pass

   elif (x == 0):
       print ("SAIU...")
       break
   else:
       print("ERRO! ")
   ```